# Adding values from 2 rows based on conditions

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table as Below....

```
ROW gvkey   datadate    CQTR    CYEARQ  Value
1   6066    3/31/2015 0:00  1   2015    3610
2   6066    12/31/2014 0:00 4   2014    16868
3   6066    9/30/2014 0:00  3   2014    10809
4   6066    6/30/2014 0:00  2   2014    6905
5   6066    3/31/2014 0:00  1   2014    3326
```

I want to get the sum of Value of 3/31/2015 and 12/31/2014. Please suggest how Can I do it in MS Sql.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this :-

```
Set Nocount On;

If Object_Id('tempdb.dbo.#table') Is Not Null
Begin
    Drop Table #table;
End

Create Table #table
(
     Id         Int Primary Key
    ,Col1       Int
    ,RDate      Datetime
    ,Col2       Int
    ,RYear      Int
    ,Col3       Int
)

Insert Into #table Values
 (1,6066,'03/31/2015 0:00',1,2015,3610)
,(2,6066,'12/31/2014 0:00',4,2014,16868) 
,(3,6066,'09/30/2014 0:00',3,2014,10809)
,(4,6066,'06/30/2014 0:00',2,2014,6905)
,(5,6066,'03/31/2014 0:00',1,2014,3326)

Select   t.Col1
        ,Sum(t.Col3) As ColSum
From    #table As t With (Nolock)
Where   t.RDate In ('03/31/2015','12/31/2014')
Group By t.Col1
```